# Creating a stored procedure with a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-migration

So this problem is interesting. Our DB is migrated via a Stored Procedure. What happens is the migration code is placed in a stored procedure such that each time new migrations are needed a new copy of the stored procedure is created with the new migration updates within it. Then the stored procedure is run to initialize the migration and then that stored procedure drops itself.

Most of the time a new column or table is created in this fashion, but how would you create a stored procedure from inside this stored procedure. It causes an error when you attempt this i.e. creating a stored procedure in a stored procedure does not seem possible in MySQL. Is there a way around this, perhaps by altering the DELIMITER yet again for the inner Stored Procedure, or maybe explicitly not altering it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.